# How to use kAudioUnitSubType_LowShelfFilter of kAudioUnitType_Effect which controls bass in core Audio?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio, ipod, bass

i'm back with one more question related to **BASS**. I already had posted this question **[How Can we control bass of music in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824207/how-can-we-control-bass-of-music-in-iphone-sdk)**, but not get as much attention of your people as it should get. But now I have done some more search and had read the **Core AUDIO**. I got one sample code which i want to share with you people here is the link to download it **[iPhoneMixerEqGraphTest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneMixerEQGraphTest/Introduction/Intro.html)**. Have a look on it in this code what i had seen is the developer had use preset Equalizer given by iPod in Apple. Lets see some code snippet too:----

```
// iPodEQ unit
CAComponentDescription eq_desc(kAudioUnitType_Effect, kAudioUnitSubType_AUiPodEQ, kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple);
```

What kAudioUnitSubType_AUiPodEQ does is it get preset values from iPod's equalizer and return us in Xcode in an array which we can use in PickerView/TableView and can set any category like bass, rock, Dance etc. It is helpless for me as it only returns names of equalizer types like bass, rock, Dance etc. as i want to implement bass only and want to implement it on UISLider.

To implement Bass on slider i need values so that i can set minimum and maximum value so that on moving slider bass can be changed.

After getting all this i start reading Core Audio's Audio Unit framework's classes and got this [image: Ipod Desc Image]
after that i start searching for bass control and got this

[image]

So now i need to implement this **kAudioUnitSubType_LowShelfFilter**. But now i don't know how to implement this enum in my code so that i can control the bass as written documentation. Even Apple had not write that how can we use it. **kAudioUnitSubType_AUiPodEQ** this category was returning us an array but **kAudioUnitSubType_LowShelfFilter** category is not returning any array. While using **kAudioUnitSubType_AUiPodEQ** this category we can use types of equalizer from an array but how can we use this category **kAudioUnitSubType_LowShelfFilter**. Can anybody help me regarding this in any manner? It would be highly appreciable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

Although it's declared in the iOS headers, the Low Shelf AU is not actually available on iOS.

---

The parameters of the Low Shelf are different from the iPod EQ.

Parameters are declared and documented in `AudioUnit/AudioUnitParameters.h':

```
// Parameters for the AULowShelfFilter unit
enum {
  // Global, Hz, 10->200, 80
  kAULowShelfParam_CutoffFrequency = 0,

  // Global, dB, -40->40, 0
  kAULowShelfParam_Gain = 1
};
```

So after your low shelf AU is created, configure its parameters using `AudioUnitSetParameter`.

Some initial parameter values you can try would be 120 Hz (kAULowShelfParam_CutoffFrequency) and +6 dB (kAULowShelfParam_Gain) -- assuming your system reproduces bass well, your low frequency content should be twice as loud.

---

> Can u tell me how can i use this kAULowShelfParam_CutoffFrequency to change the frequency.

If everything is configured right, this should be all that is needed:

```
assert(lowShelfAU);
const float frequencyInHz = 120.0f;
OSStatus result = AudioUnitSetParameter(lowShelfAU,
                                        kAULowShelfParam_CutoffFrequency,
                                        kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                        0,
                                        frequencyInHz,
                                        0);
if (noErr != result) {
  assert(0 && "error!");
  return ...;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer justin. Can u tell me how can i use this  kAULowShelfParam_CutoffFrequency to change the frequency. i'm trying to change it but when i change the value it crashes. Please help!!!

Comment: ok thanks for replying, let me check whether it works for me or not

Comment: do we need to change frequencyInHz now to change bass from minimum point to maximum point?

Comment: i had tried it, even my music stop playing now. what to do? please do something.

Comment: @NikhilBansal yes. you could set `frequencyInHz` to any value in the range `[10...200]`, then call `AudioUnitSetParameter` again.

Comment: i had used this code that you write in answer but its giving excess bad and my music stop playing too. music is stop working. the change i had done is frequencyInHz is changed by me into slider's value where slider's range is 80 to 120

Comment: @NikhilBansal i suggest you post a new question with a minimal program which reproduces the issue for others. try to detail the error and what you expect. or you can try to run with GuardMalloc and see if that helps isolate any memory-related issue. it's *highly* unlikely that setting the parameter as above is the actual source of the problem you see.

Comment: this is my new question please have a look on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033705/how-to-use-kaulowshelfparam-cutofffrequency-parameter-of-kaudiounitsubtype-lowsh

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15553/discussion-between-nikhil-bansal-and-justin)