# How to use kAULowShelfParam_CutoffFrequency parameter of kAudioUnitSubType_LowShelfFilter which controls bass in Core Audio?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-audio, bass

You must had gone through this before coming to my this question.[How to use kAudioUnitSubType_LowShelfFilter of kAudioUnitType_Effect which controls bass in core Audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881987/how-to-use-kaudiounitsubtype-lowshelffilter-of-kaudiounittype-effect-which-contr) Slowly & Steadily getting the things right for bass control of music. But yet not got succeeded in my objective. Now i got to know that i have to change the **kAULowShelfParam_CutoffFrequency** to change the **bass**.

The following code i was using before 5 to 7 days. this code plays music properly but doesn't change bass properly. have a look on this code snippet:-

```
 - (void)awakeFromNib
{
printf("AUGraphController awakeFromNib\n");

mIsPlaying = false;

// clear the mSoundBuffer struct
memset(&mUserData.soundBuffer, 0, sizeof(mUserData.soundBuffer));

// create the URLs we'll use for source A and B
NSString *sourceA = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"04 - Second Hand Jawaani - [rKmania.com]" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSString *sourceB = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Track2" ofType:@"mp4"];
sourceURL[0] = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)sourceA, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
sourceURL[1] = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)sourceB, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
[bassSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(selectEQPreset) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

// output unit
CAComponentDescription output_desc(kAudioUnitType_Output, kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO, kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple);

// iPodEQ unit
CAComponentDescription eq_desc(kAudioUnitType_Effect, kAudioUnitSubType_AUiPodEQ, kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple);

// multichannel mixer unit
CAComponentDescription mixer_desc(kAudioUnitType_Mixer, kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer, kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple);

printf("add nodes\n");

- (void)selectEQPreset;
{
AUPreset *aPreset = (AUPreset*)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(mEQPresetsArray, value);
OSStatus result = AudioUnitSetProperty(mEQ, kAudioUnitProperty_PresentPreset, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, aPreset, sizeof(AUPreset));
if (result) { printf("AudioUnitSetProperty result %ld %08X %4.4s\n", result, (unsigned int)result, (char*)&result); return; };

printf("SET EQ PRESET %d ", value);
CFShow(aPreset->presetName);
}
```

Now after this code i got to know that i have to change frequency to change the bass, then i use the following code snippet but in the following code snippet music is not playing and its giving **excess_bad** too. i'm just writing the changes i made to the code.have a look on current code snippet:-

```
// iPodEQ unit
CAComponentDescription eq_desc(kAudioUnitType_Effect, kAudioUnitSubType_LowShelfFilter, kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple);

- (void)selectEQPreset;
{
AudioUnit lowShelfAU;
assert(lowShelfAU);
float frequencyInHz = 120.0f;
frequencyInHz = bassSlider.value;
OSStatus result = AudioUnitSetParameter(lowShelfAU,kAULowShelfParam_CutoffFrequency,kAudioUnitScope_Global,0,frequencyInHz,0);
if (noErr != result) 
{
    assert(0 && "error!");
    return ;
}
}
```

**This code now i'm using but this is not changing the frequency. Its even stop playing the music and giving the excess_bad error on this line of code..**

```
 AudioUnitSetParameter(lowShelfAU,kAULowShelfParam_CutoffFrequency,kAudioUnitScope_Global,0,frequencyInHz,0);
```

Please anybody help me regarding this tell me how can i change the kAULowShelfParam_CutoffFrequency so that i can adjust the bass of music Via slider. Any help regarding this would be highly appreciable.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you can use an `AudioUnit` you need to create it.  If you're using an `AUGraph` your code will look something like:

```
AudioComponentDescription filterDescription = { kAudioUnitType_Effect, kAudioUnitSubType_LowShelfFilter, kAudioUnitSubType_LowShelfFilter, 0, 0 };

AUNode filterNode = -1;
OSStatus result = AUGraphAddNode(mAUGraph, &filterDescription, &filterNode);
if(noErr != result) {
    // Handle error
}

AudioUnit filterUnit = nullptr;
result = AUGraphNodeInfo(mAUGraph, filterNode, nullptr, &filterUnit);
if(noErr != result) {
    // Handle error
}

// Set parameters on filterUnit
```

The reason your code is failing is that the line

```
AudioUnit lowShelfAU;
```

initializes `lowShelfAU` with an undetermined value.  An `AudioUnit` is a pointer type so without initialization it points to an unknown area of memory.  I think it is a programming best practice to always initialize your variables when they are declared, to catch these kinds of bugs:

```
AudioUnit lowShelfAU = nullptr;
```

Comment: What other questions do you have?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, sorry.  What do you mean "how to implement" the code?

Comment: i'm asking how can i execute the above written code by you in my code?

Comment: I don't know what your code looks like- the code you posted in your question can't be what you're using because there is no AUGraph.

Comment: ok but can u tell me which frequency is used for bass? as now i'm getting corner frequency and center frequency too

Comment: To see how various parameters work on AudioUnits the simplest thing  is to use AULab from Apple's Core Audio Extras download.

Comment: Run Xcode and choose Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> More Developer Tools... and download Audio Tools for Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

```
`AudioUnit lowShelfAU;` <-- that is an uninitialized garbage value
```

you need to actually create an AU instance (the Low Shelf) and add it to an AUGraph.

Note: The compiler/analyzer will identify this problem for you. I recommend people turn the warning levels waaaay up, then build, analyze, and remove all issues. Repeat until clean.

Comment: do i need to make AUnode lowShelfAU and after it, do i need to add in AUGraph?

Answer (score 0):

`as you know ,apple create 3 audio units according their purpose.
remoteIO --> for input and output;mixer --> for audio mixer ;for some audio effect  is eq and Filter so,if u wanna cutoff the audio frequency,u need to create a filter unit and connect them together.